# Power Query missing "Get Data" in MS Excel 2016

Tags: excel

In Excel, under [Data] tab, I could see "From Access", "From Web", etc, but not "Get Data" option. I would like to select a folder, so to pick up multiple files. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is included in  `etc`?

Answer (score 0):

Look right a bit for the Get and Transform group, choose:

New query - From File - From folder.

Comment: This is exactly what I am after. Thanks @Rory